# What is pool in htop?

Tags: htop

What is DedicatedWorker and pool?

How can I see their thread and source in bash for instance if I want to know where pool is getting initiated and on which port it is running?

[image: Htop process]

As shown in the image, I am interested to know about the origin of the `pool` command in the htop table, if that's possible.

Comment: Press "t" when running htop to see the processes listed as a tree. Then visually follow the tree upward and you'll see the path to the executable which initiated pool.

Comment: Then try `p` to see the process's command path.

Answer (score 1):

pres `t` or `F5` followed by pressing `p` in htop, and origin will be seen.
As here 'pool' is spawned from

`light-dm -> unity -> /sbin/upstart --user`